# Erro na validação de formulário em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formulário

Estou com um erro de validação, quando aperto no botão `input` de `submit` ele não testa a `function` do JavaScript e vai logo para onde o `action` está mandando ir.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Cadastro</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function validaFormCadastro() {           
        d = document.form_cadastro;                      
        if (d.NOME.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo NOME deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.NOME.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }
        if (d.NOMEUSUARIO.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo NOME DE USUARIO deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.NOMEUSUARIO.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }           
        if (d.RM.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo RM deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.RM.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }
        if (d.SENHA.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo SENHA deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.SENHA.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form_cadastro" action="salvar_aluno.php" method="get">
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Nome completo</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="NOME">
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Nome de Usuario</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="NOMEUSUARIO">
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>RM</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="RM">
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>SENHA</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="SENHA">
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="botao_comando" value="CADASTRAR" onclick="return validaFormCadastro()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rapaz, sua função está sendo carregada, tanto em um arquivo que criei para testar, quanto nesse JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/asd7ddt3/1/ , teste e veja se este é realmente seu problema

Comment: Tente trocar o `d = document.form_cadastro` por `d = document.forms.id_form_cadastro`, no caso, seria um id, não o nome.

Comment: O teu formulário possui um input `type="submit"`, logo vai ignorar o js existente, e proceder com o envio do formulário. Uma das soluções seria colocar um substituir o evento `onclick` desse botão, por um `onblur`.

Comment: Aqui funcionou normalmente, provavelmente é algum outro script que está com erro e o resto do javascript não processa.

Answer (score 0):

A solução é na chamada do método `validaFormCadastro()` voce adicionar o `event.preventDefault();` para voltar o estado original. Tente assim:

```
    <!-- no seu input, mande como parametro o contexto do seu botao -->
    <input type="submit" name="botao_comando" value="CADASTRAR" onclick="validaFormCadastro(this)">

    <script>
    function validaFormCadastro(event) {   
        //metodo para voltar ao estado original (vai ignorar onsubmit da funcao)
        event.preventDefault();  

        d = document.form_cadastro;                      
        if (d.NOME.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo NOME deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.NOME.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }
        if (d.NOMEUSUARIO.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo NOME DE USUARIO deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.NOMEUSUARIO.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }           
        if (d.RM.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo RM deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.RM.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }
        if (d.SENHA.value == "") {                     
            alert("O campo SENHA deve ser preenchido!");                    
            d.SENHA.focus();                     
            return false;           
        }
    }
</script>
```